# How to adjust the height of two objects floating next to each other according to the amount of content, using css

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple HTML layout below that shows a class of left bar and a content area. I am planning to add style to this so that the when content is added to the content div, the height of the left bar will grow in height along with it.

```
    <body>
    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="header">
            <h1>Main Title of Web Page</h1>
        </div>

        <aside class="left">
            HTML </br>
            CSS </br>
            JavaScript </br>
        </aside>

        <aside class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, reiciendis, ea, dignissimos illum et laborum voluptate dolorem dolores vel minima fugit expedita perspiciatis est vero reprehenderit aperiam veritatis officia enim?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam, libero consequuntur nostrum sunt molestias ea similique harum voluptates officia eius distinctio impedit autem ut alias beatae neque minima suscipit facere!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, facilis harum aperiam maxime incidunt quasi eveniet iste quas atque deserunt ad accusantium amet nostrum explicabo corporis laborum tempore provident quam.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, eos, illo odit vero quo atque perspiciatis eveniet quidem necessitatibus omnis in nobis reprehenderit ea minus repellendus illum totam id. Aliquam?</p>


        </aside>

        <footer style="clear:both">
            <p>Copyright &copy; CA</p>
        </footer>


    </div>
</body>
```

Below is what I have done so far, however, when I add more content, the text overflows the div and looks ugly.

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
p{
    padding:10px 0px;
}
.wrap{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 25px auto;
}
.header{
    background-color: #faa600;
    height:100px;
    width: 960px;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.left, .content{
    height: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.left{
    float:left;
    width: 180px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #fbd917;
}
.content{
    width: 740px;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
footer{
    background-color: #faa600;
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: check this out http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: I don't think `<aside>` is the right element for your content. See http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/spec.html#the-aside-element and http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first of all, you could give them the same name of css and put a div around 1 of the same names. so you are able to make them both height 100% and you can still put them next to each other.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest fix is this:
set `.wrap` to `background-color:#fbd917;` (and remove it from `.left`) then remove the `height` attribute from your `.left, .content` selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/ybH4p/